# Backbone.js save current URL to history

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to save my application's current url / url fragment to my browser's history without necessarily knowing what that url is in my code.

Specifically, the page I'm creating allows the user to search records. When they submit the search, I'm updating the URL with a query string containing their search options, but NOT saving the new URL to the history. This is that line of code:

`Backbone.history.navigate(this.getQueryString(options), { trigger: false, replace: true });`

(I'm doing it this way so that users don't have to iterate back through previous searches to get to the page they were on before.)

Now, when the user double clicks on a record, I want to navigate to a page with that records details, but I want to save the url querystring of their last search so that they can return to it. (I've rigged my router to read querystrings and it works correctly.)

Ideally I'd like to just save the current url without having to know it. If that won't work, how can I find the current url/url fragment to do something like: 
`Backbone.history.navigate(currentURL, {trigger: false});`

Comment: That could work, or I could have getQueryString save it's last return value (or the 'options' variable) to the view each time it's called. However, I'm looking for a 'Backbone' solution, and I'm hoping that the history/router will have the capability I'm describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out after a bit more tinkering.

`Backbone.history.fragment` will return the URL fragment. (In this case, just my query string.)

So, I can achieve my desired behavior with: 
`Backbone.history.navigate(Backbone.history.fragment, false);`

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.history.location.href`

Comment: That object is undefined.

Comment: Did you `start` the history? It shouldn't be undefined.

Comment: Yes, it's started. It hasn't got a location or location.href object. However, I did find what I was looking for after all. (See my above answer.)